# Using the same potentiometer for two 555 timers

Tags: 555, potentiometer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fayxOq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have two 555 timers hooked up and I want them their duty cycle to be controlled by the same potentiometer.

The second one has twice capacitance on pin 2 so I want to be able to get the second one exactly twice slower than the first one.

If you need clarifications just let me know and I'll try to do my best to help you understand my situation.

Comment: Create a control voltage with a transistor and one potentiometer, feed this signal to two op-amps configured as buffers... Another option is to use a stereo potentiometer

Comment: If you're designing a precision spec using a capacitor, you won't be happy with the outcome

Comment: If you want the 2nd duty cycle to be double the first,  just use a divide by 2 and not a 555.

Comment: shared POT won't work .  But D FF /2 will work.   Also you can use Schmitt Inverter instead of 555 for clock with a fixed R in series = 5% or more of Pot value to limit high f range

Comment: Not sure where all these commenters are coming from. You can't buffer a control voltage, because that isn't how the 555 is using the potentiometer -- the voltage across it varies throughout the cycle. And you can't use a DFF, because that would require the first 555 to pulse twice -- and the the output of the DFF would be the 555's period, not twice its pulse width. People, please THINK before commenting off-the-cuff!

Comment: _"so I want to be able to get the second one **exactly twice slower** than the first one."_ do the outputs need to be synchronized (eg. pulse from 2nd 555 always starts at the same time as every other pulse from the first 555)? How closely do the duty cycles have to match? Why do you need this?

Comment: This is not a task for a 555.  While it sounds excessive, in reality your most economical solution is likely going to be a low end MCU reading the potentiometer via an ADC - *especially* as you have not even defined the goal to the point where it can be implemented, but only hinted at aspects which are challenging for simple circuitry but easy for software.

Comment: using DFF doesn't double duty cycle ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just configure the 2nd 555 as a frequency divider f/2, and feed it with the first. Thats a basic circuit shown in almost every 555 timer book (eg Forest M. Mimms Engineers Mini-notebook)

Comment: Using a frequency divider does not allow you to control the **duty cycle** of the second output...the duty cycle will be 50%.